# Unity Can't Figure out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity game, the script is not working, it gives me the error code
"error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property, or an indexer"
I've tried to figure out what is going on, but I can't, this error is at line 44.
Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movment : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform orientation;

    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        // calculate movment direction
        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput = orientation.right * horizontalInput;

        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Comment: `moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput = orientation.right * horizontalInput;`

Comment: How do you expect `moveDirection = firstMultiplication = secondMultiplication` to work?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput = orientation.right * horizontalInput;
```

To

```
moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;
```